# How to implement complicated animation at android platform

Tags: android, animation

Now i am developing an android app, and there are lots of animations and image resources, the ui design and the logic are also very complex. 
  I tried to use the Tween animation and android layout to implement, but the code is very complex, and i also can't implement some parts of animations.  Anyone know how to handle such complex animation at the android platform? Dose android have some tool like as flash tool to design the animation?

Comment: After read question, I am thinking what is exactly question?

Comment: @CapDroid i don't want to use the surfaceview or Tween to implement this app, because it's too difficult and the logic is too complex.I want to find a new way to develop this app which has more animations

Comment: **Anyone know how to handle such complex animation at the android platform?** there is many such complex animation.. please clear your question exactly which type of animation you want..

Comment: @CapDroid Ok, as your request, i describe what my app will do?<br>

Comment: @CapDroid Ok, 1st at the top of screen, there are 8 bubbles(3 bubbles hided). and at their top, there are 8 icons(3 icons hided). 1st, 8 bubbles scale small and large at random, after scale 10 seconds, first bubble will move to the left screen edge, and then scale 1.5 times. the small icon scale large and show a message at current big bubble. after 10s, hide it and move to the right edge of screen. other bubbles move to 1 step from original position. loop...

Answer (score 0):

In android three type of anmiations.

[1)TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

An animation that controls the position of an object

[2)ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html)

An animation that controls the scale of an object. You can specify the point to use for the center of scaling.

[3)AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html)

An animation that controls the alpha level of an object. Useful for fading things in and out. This animation ends up changing the alpha property of a Transformation

[Check this for some example.](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidQuery) for complex animations. For example, to animate all your `ImageView`s to double their current size, do:

```
$.with(this).selectByType(ImageView.class)
            .animate("{width:200%, height:200%}", 
                     new AnimationOptions().easing($.Easing.BOUNCE).duration(400));
```

You can highly customize your animation with chained methods on the `AnimationOptions` Object - from the duration and interpolator to callbacks for progress, errors, success, and completion, etc.